# Cannot read property '0' of undefined in loops

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I am trying to create a loop to find a parent element and I keep getting the error 'Cannot read property '0' of undefined'

I have tried using different kinds of loops, but to no success.  When I remove the loop completely and console.log the value, I get the right value.  Below is my current code:

```
function getGrandparent (upload) {
    var upwardsArray = [];
    upwardsArray.push(upload);
    while(true) {
        var current = _.last(upwardsArray);
        if (current[0].parent == 0) return current;
        else upwardsArray.push(getUploadByURL(current[0].parent));
    }
}
```

Comment: your `current` variable is undefined. `_.last(upwardsArray)` is not returning anything. Its not a problem with loop. Although your loop will be `infinite` if you do while(true)

Comment: At some point during the loop `current` is undefined, this would happen if `upload` was either not passed or undefined was passed to your function, or if `getUploadByURL` ever returns undefined.

Comment: @Vimsha why doesn't _.last(upwardsArray) return anything?

Comment: @DavidMckee It would be helpful to see more of the code - You can run a `console.log(upload);` between the function declaration and `var upwardsArray = [];` line to see if you really are getting `undefined` for your variable `upload`.